# Replace " (&quot;) in TinyMCE fails

Tags: tinymce, special-characters

I'm having troubles with the ["] <- sign in tinyMCE (v3.5.7).
It actually does not get replaced to [& q u o t;] which is actually needed. What it does is acutally replacing it with [& # 8 2 2 2 ;] which is the „ sign instead! .. this happens for all ["] chars, no matter where in the text they are located.

I allready tried varying the encoding type (named, numeric, raw) and to use/not use the cleanup option. Unfortunately with no effect.

Ideas?

regards

Comment: You do not need to entity " to `&quot;` for HTML validity, you do if you're inside a HTML attribute, like `<img title="Then she said "hello"" .. />` to be `<img title="Then she said &quote;hello&quote;" .. />` but in that case TinyMCE does entity the character correctly AFIAK?

Comment: If you want to manually replace " to `&quot;` for some reason, then you may want to look at adding a onBeforeSetContent and onPostProcess on init of TinyMCE that will do it for you. Let me know if you want to know how to do that.

Comment: How is straight quote getting replaced with &#8222; `&#8222;` ? Was it pasted in from somewhere or typed? Are you typing " on the keyboard and it is coming out as „ because of the user's computer's or webpage's locale settings? what language is TinyMCE set to use on init? Did you mean unicode left double quote “ character not double straight quote "?